# How to compute the derivative graph of a Python plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, derivative

I am working on the following code, which solves a system of coupled differential equations. I have been able to solve them, and I plotted one of them. I am curious how to compute and plot the derivative of this graph numerically (I know the derivative is given in the first function, but suppose I didn't have that). I was thinking that I could use a for-loop, but is there a faster way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def hiv(x,t):
    kr1 = 1e5
    kr2 = 0.1
    kr3 = 2e-7
    kr4 = 0.5
    kr5 = 5
    kr6 = 100

    h = x[0]    # Healthy Cells  -- function of time
    i= x[1]     #Infected Cells -- function of time
    v = x[2]    # Virus --  function of time

    p = kr3 * h * v
    dhdt = kr1 - kr2*h - p
    didt = p - kr4*i
    dvdt = -p -kr5*v + kr6*i
    return [dhdt, didt, dvdt]

print(hiv([1e6, 0, 100], 0))

x0 = [1e6, 0, 100]  #initial conditions
t = np.linspace(0,15,1000)   #time in years

x = odeint(hiv, x0, t)  #vector of the functions H(t), I(t), V(t)

h = x[:,0]
i = x[:,1]
v = x[:,2]

plt.semilogy(t,h)


plt.show()
```

Comment: There's numpy `diff` and `gradient`.